# I'm updating an installshield prerequisite to the latest version of the software, but can't find the GUID I'm looking for

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I've figured out how to update a prerequisite, and it seems to work when I'm working with the the latest .NET 5 Asp.NET Hosting Bundle, and I'll describe the steps I took for it here.  Then I'll show where those steps seem to fail when I try to do the same thing with the same version of the .NET Desktop Runtime.

So the steps which I can verify work are as follows.

1. I create a new prerequisite in the prerequisite editor, copying the version I'm updating.
2. I download and install manually the package I'm working on.
3. I grab the manual download link, and put it in Files To Include, replacing the existing URL.
4. I do the same with the installer, putting it in the appropriate directory and pointing InstallShield to it.
5. In Application to Run, I set the application to be the one I just pointed to.
6. Having already installed the package in step 2, I inspect the registry, under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ and manually inspect the directories there to find the GUID used to install the package.
7. I change the "Registry Key Exists" condition to point to the GUID found in the registry.
8. I create a new GUID and replace the one in Properties with it.
9. I strip out the Alternate Location for the PRQ file under the Properties tab.
10. I build and run my installer (a Basic MSI project with a single executable) and the prerequisite installs properly.

This works with the Hosting Bundle, but fails at step 6 with the Desktop Runtime.  Is there somewhere else I need to look for the registry GUID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question.  Just for completeness, I'll finish my question/guide, in the hopes it will help someone with a similar problem.  The location of the key changed sometime between 5.0.3 and 5.0.14- it no longer looks for a GUID.  Now it looks for the version number in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedhost\Version